# ¿Cómo puedo subir archivos a mi repo de Git sin usar el password?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Tengo una inquietud! Cada vez que hago un git push me pide usuario y contraseña, y yo quiero subir archivos a mi repo, pero sin que me pida la contraseña. ¿Qué tengo que hacer para que esto ocurra?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 0):

De alguna forma github tiene que saber que sos el usuario, no hay forma de hacer un git push sin antes setear tus credenciales(usuario y contraseña).

Comment: no necesariamente, una public key asociada a tu cuenta puede tener permisos de lectura escritura o ambas, por branch proyecto o total